# Are corporate user accounts OK?

Tags: discussion, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there ever a time to create a user for a company?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89868/is-there-ever-a-time-to-create-a-user-for-a-company)

I just spotted user ["Thales Nederland BV Huizen"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991318/thales-nederland-bv-huizen). It noticed it because I've worked there - it's a division of Thales Defence.

Is this kind of user account - one for a whole factory - OK?

(I can understand why they did it, though. If they're still running the same network setup, the only computer with Internet is airgapped and shared by all employees)

Comment: Why not, in a way this even reduces issues with accounts sharing the same IP.

Comment: @slhck: yeah, that's my word. +1