# Username / company association

Tags: discussion, display-names, terms-of-service, self-promotion

This question touches on *[Is there ever a time to create a user for a company?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89868/is-there-ever-a-time-to-create-a-user-for-a-company)*, but (a) is not identical and (b) The terms and conditions referenced in some answers appear to have changed.   (Specifically the T&C's no longer have references to individuals - notably this is absent from section 3.)

I run a small IT business as a one man band.  My company is thus paying for time I spend contributing answers - particularly in the Super User community where I spend quite a lot of time.

As an individual I would like to change my name on this site to something which reflects my company but also what I do there (i.e., change my username to "NetService" - which really describes what where I contribute to the site as well).    I would continue to own the username.   **Is this (now) permissible?**

Comment: As far as I can tell, it was always allowed to have name of company as display name. What wasn't allowed is to have several people use the same account.

Answer (score 7):

I see no problem with your username being the name of your company as long as you are the only person posting from your account.

In fact I do precisely that myself, and have done so for more than eight years.