# How can I share my Stack Overflow account with a team member?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, user-accounts, shared-accounts

I would like to give access to my Stack Overflow account to a member of my team.

Is it possible? If yes, how could I protect my profile data?

Comment: Doesn't that kind of, totally defeat the purpose of a trust based system where *your* reputation determines your privileges? Other companies have a corporate account (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82509/what-is-the-view-on-accounts-shared-by-multiple-users-on-stack-overflow?rq=1) and that seems to work well for them.

Comment: Why would you want to do that at all?

Comment: The TOS prohibit this, so no, don't do that.

Comment: Yes, _why_? Accounts can be had for free.

Comment: Given the confusion between [the linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82509/what-is-the-view-on-accounts-shared-by-multiple-users-on-stack-overflow?rq=1) and the terms of service this seems like a reasonable question to ask

Comment: @Cpfohl Although the accepted answer there actually stes _'Why not? Just because more than one user may manage this account doesn't devalue their contributions.'_, contrary to your evident shock of someone desiring doing just this. I don't necessarily agree, by the way, just devil's advocate, if you will.

Comment: @GrantThomas I'm quite aware my link contradicts my shock.  My shock was primarily that an individual would want to risk allowing someone else to make use of their account.  The impact would not necessarily be positive, and the benefit questionable.

Comment: @Cpfohl To be fair, they didn't give any impression they intended to do so cavalierly, and instead came here to check for such implications to avoid any "impact".

Answer (score 8):

From the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) (linked as legal in the footer):

> Stack Exchange may offer to provide the Services, as described more fully on the Network, and which are selected by Subscriber, **solely for Subscriber’s own use**, and not for the use or benefit of any third party.

(emphasis mine)

Additionally:

> Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is **an individual** (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age.

(thanks @Mat, emphasis his)

Comment: The "_Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is **an individual** (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age._" bit may (or may not, IANAL) be necessary to rule out (or not) a "corporate account".